# Errors in Racket for SICP Exercise 1.11

Tags: racket, sicp

The interpreter for Racket gives me errors

in my attempt to implement the recursive

function for Exercise 1.11:

```
#lang sicp

(define (f n)
  (cond ((< n 3) n)
        (else (+ f((- n 1)) 
                 (* 2 f((- n 2))) 
                 (* 3 f((- n 3)))))))

(f 2)
(f 5)
```

The errors given by the Racket intrepreter are:

```
 2
 application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
 given: 4
 arguments...: [none]
 context...:
```

/Users/tanveersalim/Desktop/Git/EPI/EPI/Functional/SICP/chapter_1/exercise_1-11.rkt: [running body]

Comment: You're calling `f` incorrectly in the procedure definition; the parenthesis goes before the `f` not after.

Comment: Your advice worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others noted, you're calling `f` incorrectly

Change `f((- n 1))` (and other similar instances) to `(f (- n 1))`

```
(define (f n)
  (cond ((< n 3) n)
        (else (+ (f (- n 1)) 
                 (* 2 (f (- n 2))) 
                 (* 3 (f (- n 3)))))))

(f 2) ; 2
(f 5) ; 25
```